# Silex SwiftMailer Not Making SMTP Connection Upon Execution

Tags: php, swiftmailer, silex

I am making a console application which uses the SwiftMail extension to send. Due to our policy, I have two virtual machines, one which serves as a SMTP relay and the other which is the application server. Sending mail manually through telnet to the relay works fine. When using SwiftMail, it's broken.

The headers are returned and there are no entries returned in the `$failure` variable for `send()`

Response of `getHeaders()->toString()`

```
Message-ID: <1351104631.508838778dc03@swift.generated>
Date: Wed, 24 Oct 2012 14:50:31 -0400
Subject: [YourSite] Feedback
From: noreply@localhost.com
To: sixeightzero@localhost.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

If I echo the `send()`, i get `1`.

**boot.php**

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SwiftmailerServiceProvider(), array(
    'swiftmailer.options' => array(
        'host' => 'ip.host.relay',
        'port' => 25,
        'encryption' => null,
        'auth_mode' => null
    ),
));
```

**app.php**

```
 $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance( )
        ->setSubject('[YourSite] Feedback')
        ->setFrom(array('noreply@localhost.com'))
        ->setTo(array('sixeightzero@localhost.com'))
        ->setBody("Message!");


    $app['mailer']->send($message, $failures);
```

When i run a TCP dump on the app server and run the script, there are no SMTP connection made, and there are no errors thrown.

Anyone encounter this before? I don't want to use sendmail or mail, but SMTP due to our application requirements.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the sending server with something else to be sure it's running/listening?

Comment: Yes, I telnetted to the relay from the app server and successfully simulated a message, which was received. I don't see any outbound SMTP traffic when running `app.php` on the app server, and no inbound SMTP on the relay

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is because the `SwiftmailerServiceProvider` uses a `Swift_MemorySpool` by default, and only flushes that on `kernel.terminate`. Let me take a step back and explain each part of this.

- The `SwiftmailerServiceProvider` is responsible for registering the Swiftmailer services and default configuration. By default the transport (`swiftmailer.spooltransport`) is `Swift_SpoolTransport` and the `swiftmailer.spool` is `Swift_MemorySpool`.
- Swiftmailer supports different ways of sending the mails. These are called transports. The spool transport acts as a queue. You can either store this queue in a file or in memory. Spool transports have a `flushQueue` method which allows flushing the queued mails to a real transport, which should deliver them.
- The Symfony2 HttpKernel which Silex uses emits a number of events during the lifecycle of every request. The last one that it emits is the `kernel.terminate` event. This event is triggered after the HTTP response body has been sent. This allows you to do heavy tasks after rendering the page, so that it no longer appears as loading to the user.
- The `SwiftmailerServiceProvider` subscribes to the `kernel.terminate` event in order to flush the memory spool after the page has been rendered. It flushes it to `swiftmailer.transport` service, which is a `Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport` that does the actual sending via SMTP.

So let's get to the actual problem. You are in a CLI context, so none of those HttpKernel events will be fired. And since the `kernel.terminate` event is not fired, your spool is not being flushed. And thus your emails are not getting sent.

There's two good solutions for this:

- A) Flush the spool manually. Just do what the provider does in its listener. Add this at the end of your CLI command:

  ```
  if ($app['mailer.initialized']) {
      $app['swiftmailer.spooltransport']->getSpool()->flushQueue($app['swiftmailer.transport']);
  }
  ```
- B) Re-configure the `mailer` service to use the ESMTP transport directly without going through the spool:

  ```
  $app['mailer'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
      return new \Swift_Mailer($app['swiftmailer.transport']);
  });
  ```

Either solution should do. Good luck!

Comment: Perfect, that's kinda what I came up with on my own, but that works great. went with option `B`. Thanks @igorw!